# Switch Fedora to Ubuntu by replacing files

Tags: system-installation

I managed to run Fedora 25 in Termux on my android phone but I want to switch it to Ubuntu. Can I replace some files of Fedora system with files of Ubuntu system to run Ubuntu on my phone directly? If possible, which files should I replace? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't switch distros just by changes some files.  A distro will actually have to be installed.  There are many libraries and dependencies that will have to be in the right place with proper configuration for an OS to work.  Various distros have those dependencies placed in different areas.  They even have some of the library names specified with different spellings.

To have support from this forum (I'm sure the same would go for trying to ge support from with Fedora from their support channel) you would have to have a correct installation with all the files in the proper place.

To try to run a distro without actually installing it, and just have files from different distros will leave you with two unsupported broken distros.

By the way, some of what you have described is what is involved with creating a new distro.  It takes a very dedicated group to perform the task.  The results would be a different distro, by a different name with a totally different support group.